# Designing suggestions with Java and JSON file in a webapp

Tags: java, json, jsp, concurrency, io

I need your feedback and suggestions on a design.

**I have (can not be changed):**

1. Web application (JSP/Servlets)
2. JSON file on server (database)

**Use case:**

1. Concurrent read of information from JSON
2. synchronized write of information

Let me explain the problem:

The JSON file basically has information like:

```
{
  "modules": {
    "module1": {
      "sub-module1": {
        "info": "some faq statememt"
      },
      "sub-module2": {
        "info": "some faq statememt"
      }
    },
    "module2": {
      "sub-module1": {
        "info": "info on module2: submodule1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now all users can read information via JSP by requesting any module, then submodule.
The program basically gets the requested info, loads the JSON file, maps it to model object and returns relevant information back to JSP, via AJAX.

And admin users can edit existing information by adding new keys/information
or by editing existing information.

**Constraint**: Same key editing will not be done by multiple admins.

I have written the application but now concurrency is up on my head.
At this moment, the file is accessed via FileInputStream and FileOutputStream.

**I have following questions and I need answers for them as I dont have much knowledge on IO:**

1. What happens if writing is taking long time, then will the read throw exception? How to handle this?
2. How to make sure of concurrent reads and synchronized write successfully? Probably write method can be synchronized on a singleton object of Data Access class, but then how do we take care of read requests?
3. Since for fetching existing information, or writing back, the whole JSON object is mapped (using Boon) to main model in my program, and I fear this might one day lead to heavy deadlock or memory issue. How to evade this?

Comment: How many keys will there typically be?

Comment: There can be nearly 15-20 modules, each having nearly 3-4 submodules, and each submodule containing info that can be nearly as big as two A4 size page contents, mostly will be less. But these constraints are not fixed, I am trying to make the application future proof.

Comment: How many keys does a sub module have?

Comment: They don't have, I have attached sample JSON in question. Its stays same with minor changes if needed be.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by your answer in comments you could maybe get away with keeping a monitor object in memory for each key and then synchronize the writing code on the key'
s monitor. This would avoid concurrent access whilst maintaining some level of performance. However this should all be avoided by using a nosql database or some other tool instead of directly reading/writing a file.

EDIT: So it turns out you only have around 80 keys. You could keep that small amount of data in memory and handle concurrent access with java synchronization. Just add a background job which writes the data to disk now and then.

Answer (score 0):

For the question-2;

In Java, servlets are singleton objects by their nature and if you have concerns about thread-safety, you should definitely use a wrapper class and create instances per requests to prevent from *Race Condition*

> For a servlet not hosted in a distributed environment (the default),
>   the servlet container must use only one instance per servlet
>   declaration. However, for a servlet implementing the SingleThreadModel
>   interface, the servlet container may instantiate multiple instances to
>   handle a heavy request load and serialize requests to a particular
>   instance.

Comment: the data access class is not a servlet.

Comment: but your servlet is. That's why you should wrap your servlet which has access directly to your DataAccess class.